# Javascript asynchronous events

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, callback

I'm trying to understand callbacks, so I created a test code to check async behavior.

```
function wait() {
while (new Date() < 2000 + new Date().getTime()){}
console.log("end");
}

console.log("start");
wait();

function clicke(){
console.log("click!")
}

document.addEventListener('click', clicke);
```

So I expect to logs put `start` then `clicks` when I do them and 2 secs later `end`. But the issue is all event notifications come after `start` and `end` printed out.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This has nothing to do with asynchronous behavior. This has more to do with `sleep`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asynchronous means that a tread is running besides another thread. However your browser isn't multithreaded, it's single threaded. It will run code in the order it is presented. It will try to finish the `while loop` you've created before going on to the next line. The GUI is also hooked into that thread. You are basically blocking the *GUI* during the `while loop` *ergo* the page becomes unresponsive.

Additions to JavaScript were made to circumvent hanging the main thread. Ajax calls are asynchronous, because you don't want xml-files that are some *5 mb* big render the browser useless during loading. Also the original `setTimeout` and `setInterval` allow for asynchronous operations. They don't block the thread, but run aside it.

New techniques are being developed and implemented like `promises` that also allow for asynchronous call, but you can chain functions to the asynchronous object.

Asynchronous handling with an example:

```js
function start() {
  document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Started, you have ten seconds to click as much as you can.</p> ";
  var callback = function(){alert("Game Over")};
  document.addEventListener('click', clicke);  
  setTimeout('end('+callback+')', 10000); //send the callback to end the function end.
}

start();

var clicked = 0;
function clicke(){
 document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Clicked: "+ (clicked++) +"</p> "
}

function end(callback)
{
  document.body.innerHTML += "<p>Ended, you can no longer click.</p> ";
  document.removeEventListener('click', clicke);
  callback();
}
```

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript is single-threaded and the while loop blocks the thread.  After two seconds of busy-waiting in that while loop, it handles the events you're creating.  To log a message at two seconds, do this:

```
setTimeout(function(){console.log("message")}, 2000);
```

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setTimeout